# CREATE VIEW Statement in Acumatica Customization Project

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Does anyone know how to push a CREATE VIEW SQL statement into an Acumatica Customization Project?

I know how to do it in SQL Management Studio, but doing it through a Customization Project would be useful for Acumatica SaaS customers.

Comment: views are not recommended, however you can just do a SQL Script in a customization project to create the view, then create a DAC for that View

Comment: Brendan is correct as per standard customization.

Though you could still. Once view is created you can add it as a DAC in Customization. It would be best to have a link attributes for drill down functionalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform the following steps:

1. Create your SQL View in Management Studio (for demo purposes let me stick to a simple PositivePay view):

   ```
   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PositivePay] AS
   SELECT
       APPayment.RefNbr,
       APPayment.ExtRefNbr,
       APRegister.DocDate,
       APRegister.OrigDocAmt,
       CashAccount.ExtRefNbr BankAccountID
   FROM APPayment 
   JOIN APRegister 
       ON APRegister.CompanyID = APPayment.CompanyID 
           AND APRegister.RefNbr = APPayment.RefNbr 
   JOIN CashAccount 
       ON APPayment.CashAccountID = CashAccount.AccountID 
           AND APPayment.CompanyID = CashAccount.CompanyID 
   WHERE APPayment.CompanyID = 2 AND APPayment.DocType= 'CHK'
   GO
   ```
2. Open your customization project and click on **Code**, then generate new DAC based on your SQL view as shown in the screenshot below:
   [image]
3. Define key fields for your new DAC and save changes. For PositivePay we set **IsKey** to ***true*** for the PXDBString attribute on top of the RefNbr field:

   ```
   [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "", IsKey = true)]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ref Nbr")]
   public string RefNbr { get; set; }
   ```
4. Click on **DB Scripts**, select your SQL view name in **DBObject Name** and put SQL script into the **Custom Script** control following the pattern below:

   ```
   IF EXISTS
   (
       SELECT * FROM sys.views
       WHERE name = 'PositivePay' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
   )
   DROP VIEW [dbo].[PositivePay]
   GO

   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PositivePay] AS
   SELECT
       APPayment.RefNbr,
       APPayment.ExtRefNbr,
       APRegister.DocDate,
       APRegister.OrigDocAmt,
       CashAccount.ExtRefNbr BankAccountID
   FROM APPayment 
       JOIN APRegister 
           ON APRegister.CompanyID = APPayment.CompanyID 
               AND APRegister.RefNbr = APPayment.RefNbr 
       JOIN CashAccount 
           ON APPayment.CashAccountID = CashAccount.AccountID 
               AND APPayment.CompanyID = CashAccount.CompanyID 
   WHERE APPayment.CompanyID = 2 AND APPayment.DocType= 'CHK'
   GO
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for this @RuslanDev. This is awesome.

Comment: Added for clarity - once such package is published in SaaS environment, system will create the SQL view along with other components present in the package.